# Which IPs can't be used in a GCP virtual network?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I've tried searching this question in different ways and can't seem to find the documentation. I think it's the first 2 and the last one, but I'm also thinking there's maybe 4 IP addresses that can't be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reserved IP addresses in IPv4 subnets**

Every subnet has four reserved IP addresses in its primary IP range. There are no reserved IP addresses in the secondary IP ranges. [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/subnets#reserved_ip_addresses_in_every_subnet)

The first, second, second to last and last are reserved. For example, a /24 network:

```
192.168.0.0 - Network
192.168.0.1 - Default Gateway
192.168.0.254 - Reserved for future use
192.168.0.255 - Broadcast
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried searching gcp reserved ip address and the only thing that comes up is the concept of Reserving Static IP address, so this was helpful

Comment: 'you can thank John by giving an upvote. Add comment recommendation is to avoid "thanks"